# Does the maximum likelihood estimate give the optimal line of fit in a QQ plot?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, qq-plot

Many analysts attempt to fit a distribution for a random variable by a. estimating the parameters with maximum likelihood then b. assessing the quality of the fit to the distribution by inspecting a QQ plot. They then use the QQ plot to qualitatively assess whether they believe the distributional fit is good or not; in other words they infer whether the *distribution* is correctly specified or not when the choice of model parameter may not be fit for purpose.

I think a caveat with this approach may be that the maximum likelihood estimate may not necessarily produce the "optimal" concordance line along the QQ plot. I am using the word "optimal" loosely because it's not exactly clear how our eyes interpret quality of fit. If I focus on OLS errors, I find that directly optimizing the QQ plot produces *slightly* different results.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rgamma(20000, 15, 4)
# x <- x^1.05

nll <- function(param) {
  -sum(dgamma(x, param[1], param[2], log=T))
}
val <- nlm(nll, c(4,1))
mle <- val$estimate
pp <- ppoints(20000)
plot(qgamma(pp, mle[1], mle[2]), sort(x))
abline(0,1)

f <- function(param) {
  tq <- qgamma(pp, param[1], param[2])
  sum((sort(x) - tq)^2)
}
nlm(f, p=c(m, s))$estimate
mle
```

Gives a fairly discrepant estimates for N=20,000:

```
> nlm(f, p=c(m, s))$estimate
[1] 15.059903  4.025618
> mle
[1] 15.132561  4.044874
```

Is it rounding error or numerical inconsistency? I don't know.

Comment: The values in the QQ plot are order statistics - they are not I.i.d, their variances differ and their covariances are non-zero, so MLE is not the same as OLS there.